# Add Clone Functionality to LWC Datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a lightning data table and have added an action to "clone" the selected record. I'm unsure of how to go about copying fields from the selected record and creating a new record.

I was using a lightning-record-edit-form without the id.  I'm just unsure of how I go about this.  I tried this in the action but it does not set the group number field.

```
 // From Row Action Dropdown - Edit record
  cloneCurrentRecord(currentRow) {
    // open modal box
    this.bShowModal = true;
    this.isEditForm = false;
    this.isReadForm = false;
    this.isCloneForm = true;

    // assign record id to the record edit form
    this.currentRecordId = currentRow.Id;
    this.Group_Number__c = currentRow.Group_Number__c;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  thanks!

Fred

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out as soon as I posted this.  I need to create a variable to hold each field value in the method.  For example, mygroupnumber.  In the field under the form, I set the value...  value={mygroupnumber}